# magento getURL path always add "admin"

Tags: admin, transactional-mail, geturl

I try to generate a link, by using getURL, but some how it keep adding "admin" behind my hostname, what should I do? getURL cannot use in this case?

It use to send out transnational email, if sending thru admin panel, the path on email template will have "admin" which is I don't want this happen.

Please help

Comment: Try this https://www.mageplaza.com/devdocs/how-get-base-url-current-url-magento-2.html

Comment: add your email_tenmplate.xml file code

Comment: so can you share me screenshot of code? or email or else? as well getURL where you put?

Answer (score 0):

get Store base url try this

```
protected $_storeManager;

public function __construct(
    .......................................................
    .......................................................
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
    .......................................................
    .......................................................
) {
    .......................................................
    .......................................................
    $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
    .......................................................
    .......................................................
}

public function execute()
{

    echo $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl();
}
```